# ¿Es posible usar SwitchListTile dentro de showModalBottomSheet en Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

Quisiera saber si es posible usar SwitchListTile dentro de showModalBottomSheet en Flutter.
Lo he intentado

```
SwitchListTile(
       value: habilita,
      title: Text('Habilitar'),
   
      onChanged: ( value ) {
      setState ((){
        habilita = value;
              
      });
    }
  )
```

Al hacerlo habilita toma su valor,  pero visualmente no se ve el switch.

Comment: sí, es posible, create un Stateful widget y llámalo dentro del showModalBottomSheet ,   dentro de ese stateful agrega el SwitchListTile, ahí usa el setState y verás como cambia visualmente

Comment: si, estoy usando un Stateful widget.  dentro del showModalBottomSheet, tengo un formulario  que contiene ademas del SwitchListTile  un TextFormField y  un DropdownButtonFormField que funcionan correctamente. Mis disculpas, llevo poco tiempo con flutter.

Comment: Lo que está dentro del showModal... Debe ser un widget separado, puedes agregar más código a tu pregunta? Para poder observar el error

Comment: Si. Ya entendí y resolví el problema que tenía. Fue de mucha ayuda su explicación. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @diegoveloper deberías poner eso como respuesta (añadiendo algo más de detalle y algún ejemplo de código a ser posible)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ahí agregué la respuesta, yani, si te sirve puedes marcarla como válida.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problem común, también me pasó.

Cuando usamos `StatefulWidget` tenemos que crear un `State`, dentro de ese estado podemos actualizarlo constantemente usando `setState`, esto nos permite repintar el widget (previas validaciones), es decir, vuelve a pasar por el método `build` del State.

Cuando abrimos un modal, como es el caso que muestras: `showModalBottomSheet` , estás creando una rama nueva al mismo nivel del State que ya tienes.

Es decir, cuando estás llamando a `setState` aquí, solo estás actualizando el estado anterior, más no el del modal que abriste.

```dart
SwitchListTile(
       value: habilita,
      title: Text('Habilitar'),
   
      onChanged: ( value ) {
      setState ((){
        habilita = value;
              
      });
    }
  )
```

Hay varias soluciones para esto, entre las más sencillas son, o usar el widget `StatefulBuilder`  dentro de tu modal.
Ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syvT63CosNE

O como te dije en el comentario, extraer esos widgets que usas dentro del modal y crear uno con su propio estado (un StatefulWidget):

```dart
showModalBottomSheet ( TuStatefulWidget )
```

Entonces ya luego dentro de `TuStatefulWidget` podrás usar el `setState` sin problemas.